# unrecognized selector sent to instance in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm using a segue in code from one view controller to another view controller, they are both embedded in a Navigation Controller, the segue is "Show".

This is how I call the segue:

```
        performSegueWithIdentifier("LogIn", sender: self)
```

And this is what I do:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "LogIn"  {
            segue.destinationViewController.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
        }

    }
```

And as soon as the segue is triggered I get an error in Xcode :

```
[Chooze.LogInOrRegisterViewController setShowsCancelButton:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f928b93aed0
2014-09-23 16:40:04.608 Chooze[9935:939290] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Chooze.LogInOrRegisterViewController setShowsCancelButton:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f928b93aed0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the destination view controller is embedded in a navigation controller, your code is trying to invoke `setShowsCancelButton` on the navigation controller. Instead, you should access the navigation controller's `topViewController` property, and call `setShowsCancelButton` on the object it returns, for example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if segue.identifier == "Login" {
        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let controller = navController.topViewController as LoginOrRegisterViewController
        controller.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: on this line `controller.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)` I get the following error : "LogInOrRegisterViewController does not have a member named `setShowsCancelButton`

Comment: Then why are you trying to call that method? You haven't posted any code for that class, so there's no way to guess what it does.

Comment: I was using the same method in objective - c , I'm just trying to write exactly the same in swift, this is in objective - c `[(segue.destinationViewController) setShouldHideBackButton:YES];`

Comment: Then wouldn't it be `controller.shouldHideBackButton = true`? Where is `setShowsCancelButton` coming from? Please post code rather than turning this into a long, boring comment thread. :-)